# As $a \in\left\{ 1,2,3 \right\}~~$ is held, can I write $f(a=1)=k~~$ rather than $\text{As}~a=1, f(a)=f(1)=k~~$?

Tags: notation

$$  x \in\left\{1,2,3\right\}  $$

$$  f(x):=\text{function which returns certain value depending on argument }x $$

Assume the below statements .

$$ \text{As }x=1 ~,~  $$

$$  f(x)=f(1)=k $$

Can I write it as the below notation?

$$  f(x=1)=k $$

I want to know whether teachers subtract of scores or not as the above notation.

The purpose to write as my way is just I want to save the time.

Comment: Just write $f(1)=k$ where by $k$ is meant the output of $f$ for input $1.$

Comment: To me personally, the expression $f(x=1)$ is nonstandard and confusing, so I don't see how using it would be worth the time saved. I mean, it's not like "$f(x)$" is that much of a hassle to write...

Answer (score -1):

I think that you want to underline the fact that $f$ Is a function on $x$ and that if $x=1$ $f(1)=k$, I Would writer $f(x)|_{x=1}$